# How to config swager that generate UI with methods ordered like in controller

Tags: java, swagger

Is there any way to config swagger to make generation UI ordered like it was in java class

```
public class someController{

method1(){}
method2(){}
```

and need to generate in same order

- get method1
- get method2

Comment: Correct the spelling of your technical terms

Comment: seems like it swagger bug https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3033

Comment: they use hashmap  to deal with methods instead of LinkedHashMap - that be able to do original order.....